# IDE for Play 2.0 framework and Scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm recently playing with Play 2.0. I found in the docs that it can generate a project for Eclipse, Idea or Netbeans. However it seems this works only for pre-2.0 versions.

How do you configure a Play 2.0 project for IntelliJ Idea, or what other IDE would you recommend?

Answer (score 8):

At the time of the question Play 2.0 was still in beta and lacked some support and documentation. Recently they've released methods to automatically generate the files you need to import your project into some IDE.

Do the following:

1. Create your project
2. Go to the folder of the project
3. Run `play` to open the `sbt` console
4. Run `eclipse` to create an Eclipse project
5. Run `idea` to create an IntelliJ Idea project

Enjoy hacking! :)

Comment: I assume "Run `eclipse`" is either outdated, or is a typo for "Run `eclipsify`".

Comment: @Arjan most likely outdated, that was from Beta :)

Comment: actually, "run eclipsify" is by now outdated, I think it was used in Play 2.0, but was changed to "run eclipse" in Play 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

Play2.0 is still in active development. IDE support will be available, but not quite yet. It is worth keeping an eye on the nightly builds as there have been discussions about the IDE support recently, so it may be coming soon!

Answer (score 4):

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/IDE

Please check the documentation here.

Answer (score 2):

If you build the git-Version you can use the eclipsify-command (I assume idealize will be there too). Another approach is to use [sbt-eclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse). Unfortunately the project is under heavy development too. The stable version doesn't work under windows, but the head version does.

Comment: "idealize" is great news! I'll try the git-version than. I assume you understand freshest sources by that? Isn't there some nightly build?

Comment: Args I make a try and idealize doesn't work, perhaps idea has a good sbt-support? I'm unsure because I prefer eclipse. git-version==freshest source.

Comment: I just tried idealize and as you said, it doesn't work (I've read you comment just now). I believe there is sbt support in IDEA, but how can it help me set the project for this IDE? (I don't know SBT).

Comment: As far as I understand each play20-project is an sbt-project. So if idea support sbt it should support play20. With sbt-eclipse it works only the views wasn't in classpath. How ever I didn't find time to evaluate it deeply. At the moment it's all experimental.

Answer (score 2):

I voted for Intellij IDEA 12.
It support play 2.0 natively.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend intellij IDEA 12:

- it has syntax highlighting in scala templates; you can go from a
  controller action to a corresponding view with only one click;
- also you can compile your project right from IDE and it will start a browser for you;
- and you still have all the other benefits of this IDE such as refactoring which works for scala too.

As other guys have mentioned already you simply type 'play idea' in your command console and you can open your project from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use **SublimeText 3** for developing with Play. There is a **plugin** for that available [here](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-sublimetext2) which enables syntax highlighting for all the filetypes used in play. It seems to be for SublimeText 3 but I have not yet encountered any problems with Sublime 3. If you have [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) installed this plugin is even in the default repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Using 2.0.3, I was able to [finally] get this all to work by running `play idea`, and then just opening that directory in IDEA (rather than importing it). If I tried to set it up myself, the classpath never seemed to be working.